# How to apply pandas data on word2vec

Tags: pandas, nlp, word2vec, cpu-word

I am trying to use W2V.
I saved my preprocessed data as a pandas dataframe, and I want to apply the word2vec algorithm to my preprocessed data.

This is my data.
http://naver.me/IFjLAHld

This is my code.

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('re_nlp0820.xlsx')

model = Word2Vec(df['nlp'],
                 sg=1,           
                 window=3,       
                 min_count=1,     
                 workers=4,       
                 iter=1)        
model.init_sims(replace=True) 

model_result1 = model.wv.most_similar('국민', topn =20)  
print(model_result1)
```

Please, help me

Answer (score 3):

First you need to convert the data you are passing to the Word2Vec instance into a **nested list** where each list contains the **tokenized form of the text**. You can do so by:

```
from gensim.models.word2vec import Word2Vec
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import nltk

df = pd.read_excel('re_nlp0820.xlsx')

nlp = [nltk.word_tokenize(i) for i in df['nlp']]

model = Word2Vec(nlp,
                 sg=1,           
                 window=3,       
                 min_count=1,     
                 workers=4,       
                 iter=1)        
model.init_sims(replace=True) 

model_result1 = model.wv.most_similar('국민', topn =20)  
print(model_result1)
```

Comment: FYI, you need a closing apostrophe on df['nlp'].

Answer (score 0):

Gensim's `Word2Vec` needs as its training corpus a re-iterable sequence, where each item is a list-of-words.

You `df['nlp']` is probably just a sequence of strings, so it's not in the right format. You should make sure each of its items is broken into a Python `list` that has your desired words as individual strings.

(Separately: `min_count=1` is almost always a bad idea with this algorithm, which gives better results if rare words with few usage examples are discarded. And, you shouldn't need to call `.init_sims()` at all.)

Comment: Thank you so much!
All I need to do now is find a way to turn the pandas data into individual list data.
Actually I don't know how to convert pandas data into individual list data.
I'll apply other advice as well.
thanks